Calling MS Access custom functions from Excel VBA in query
this is a rather generic question related to MS Access and Excel VBA. Suppose we have the typical car sales database, CAR.accdb. From an Excel VBA module I can easily query this database after connecting to it (ADODB). But what if I want to run a query, again from Excel VBA, that uses a custom function? In the CAR.accdb database I created a new module and inside a custom function, but when I use it in the Excel VBA query I get the message "Undefined function 'xxx' in expression".
So my question is, is it possible to use a custom function in this context (it would be a fairly complex function, using Split, etc) and if so what am I doing wrong? Is It possible to create the function in Excel VBA and use it in the query rather than create the function in the Access file?
Thank you, I appreciate any guidance.
